# Will and When Undertow hanlde all incoming requests with a single IO-Thread

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, undertow

**Here is my problem:**

[Please refer to the snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bAIdO.png)

[snapshot of logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S2eJP.png)

```
2018-12-01 16:03:24.634  INFO 11528 --- [   XNIO-1 I/O-1] com.asrapi.handler.ASRHandler      : 收到Up请求, id=76cfe0da-6f09-43ef-91a4-53c395387aa4, ak=ca5a1988599987899435bd51e76e2d5c73605519
2018-12-01 16:03:24.634  INFO 11528 --- [   XNIO-1 I/O-1] com.asrapi.access.TokenManager     : 当前Token: ca5a1988599987899435bd51e76e2d5c73605519, 不存在: false
2018-12-01 16:03:24.650  INFO 11528 --- [   XNIO-1 I/O-1] com.asrapi.service.HTTPService     : receive msg: 1,  耗时: 16
2018-12-01 16:03:24.651  INFO 11528 --- [pool-1-thread-1] com.asrapi.service.HTTPService     : Up上行 POST-ASR开始：1543651404651
2018-12-01 16:03:24.793  INFO 11528 --- [   XNIO-1 I/O-1] com.asrapi.service.HTTPService     : receive msg: 2,  耗时: 159
2018-12-01 16:03:24.964  INFO 11528 --- [   XNIO-1 I/O-1] com.asrapi.service.HTTPService     : receive msg: 2,  耗时: 330
2018-12-01 16:03:25.138  INFO 11528 --- [   XNIO-1 I/O-1] com.asrapi.service.HTTPService     : receive msg: 2,  耗时: 504
2018-12-01 16:03:25.306  INFO 11528 --- [   XNIO-1 I/O-1] com.asrapi.service.HTTPService     : receive msg: 2,  耗时: 672
2018-12-01 16:03:25.470  INFO 11528 --- [   XNIO-1 I/O-1] com.asrapi.service.HTTPService     : receive msg: 2,  耗时: 836
2018-12-01 16:03:25.641  INFO 11528 --- [   XNIO-1 I/O-1] com.asrapi.service.HTTPService     : receive msg: 2,  耗时: 1007
2018-12-01 16:03:25.805  INFO 11528 --- [   XNIO-1 I/O-1] com.asrapi.service.HTTPService     : receive msg: 2,  耗时: 1171
2018-12-01 16:03:25.971  INFO 11528 --- [   XNIO-1 I/O-1] com.asrapi.service.HTTPService     : receive msg: 2,  耗时: 1337
2018-12-01 16:03:26.110  INFO 11528 --- [   XNIO-1 I/O-1] com.asrapi.handler.ASRHandler      : 收到Down请求, id=76cfe0da-6f09-43ef-91a4-53c395387aa4, ak=ca5a1988599987899435bd51e76e2d5c73605519
2018-12-01 16:03:26.110  INFO 11528 --- [   XNIO-1 I/O-1] com.asrapi.access.TokenManager     : 当前Token: ca5a1988599987899435bd51e76e2d5c73605519, 不存在: false
2018-12-01 16:03:26.110  INFO 11528 --- [pool-1-thread-1] com.asrapi.service.HTTPService     : Down下行 POST-ASR开始：1543651406110
2018-12-01 16:03:26.191  INFO 11528 --- [t.baidu.com/...] com.asrapi.service.HTTPService     : Down POST-ASR响应总耗时：81
2018-12-01 16:03:26.191  INFO 11528 --- [t.baidu.com/...] com.asrapi.service.HTTPService     : http://audiotest.baidu.com/open_asr_test/down?id=76cfe0da-6f09-43ef-91a4-53c395387aa4, resp_code:200
2018-12-01 16:03:26.191  INFO 11528 --- [t.baidu.com/...] com.asrapi.service.HTTPService     : http://audiotest.baidu.com/open_asr_test/down?id=76cfe0da-6f09-43ef-91a4-53c395387aa4, resp_message:OK
2018-12-01 16:03:26.191  INFO 11528 --- [t.baidu.com/...] com.asrapi.service.HTTPService     : http://audiotest.baidu.com/open_asr_test/down?id=76cfe0da-6f09-43ef-91a4-53c395387aa4, resp_encoding:chunked
2018-12-01 16:03:26.191  INFO 11528 --- [t.baidu.com/...] com.asrapi.service.HTTPService     : http://audiotest.baidu.com/open_asr_test/down?id=76cfe0da-6f09-43ef-91a4-53c395387aa4, resp_protocol:http/1.1
2018-12-01 16:03:26.191  INFO 11528 --- [t.baidu.com/...] com.asrapi.service.HTTPService     : ASR response, type: 4, time: 1543651406191
2018-12-01 16:03:36.090  INFO 11528 --- [t.baidu.com/...] com.asrapi.service.HTTPService     : ASR response, type: 5, time: 1543651416090
2018-12-01 16:03:36.090  INFO 11528 --- [   XNIO-1 I/O-1] com.asrapi.utils.ASRUtil           : Web response type: 5
2018-12-01 16:03:36.091  INFO 11528 --- [   XNIO-1 I/O-1] com.asrapi.utils.ASRUtil           : Last NLU response type: 5
id: "76cfe0da-6f09-43ef-91a4-53c395387aa4"
err_no: -3001
err_msg: "server read sdk error, not ltv struct"
last <
>

2018-12-01 16:03:36.093  INFO 11528 --- [   XNIO-1 I/O-1] com.asrapi.service.HTTPService     : receive msg: 2,  耗时: 11459
2018-12-01 16:03:36.093  INFO 11528 --- [   XNIO-1 I/O-1] com.asrapi.service.HTTPService     : receive msg: 2,  耗时: 11459
2018-12-01 16:03:36.093  INFO 11528 --- [   XNIO-1 I/O-1] com.asrapi.service.HTTPService     : receive msg: 2,  耗时: 11459
2018-12-01 16:03:36.093  INFO 11528 --- [   XNIO-1 I/O-1] com.asrapi.service.HTTPService     : receive msg: 2,  耗时: 11459
2018-12-01 16:03:36.093  INFO 11528 --- [   XNIO-1 I/O-1] com.asrapi.service.HTTPService     : receive msg: 2,  耗时: 11459
2018-12-01 16:03:36.093  INFO 11528 --- [   XNIO-1 I/O-1] com.asrapi.service.HTTPService     : receive msg: 2,  耗时: 11459
2018-12-01 16:03:36.093  INFO 11528 --- [   XNIO-1 I/O-1] com.asrapi.service.HTTPService     : receive msg: 3,  耗时: 11459
2018-12-01 16:03:36.110  INFO 11528 --- [t.baidu.com/...] com.asrapi.service.HTTPService     : http://audiotest.baidu.com/open_asr_test/down?id=76cfe0da-6f09-43ef-91a4-53c395387aa4, response text: 
2018-12-01 16:03:36.126  INFO 11528 --- [t.baidu.com/...] com.asrapi.service.HTTPService     : Up POST-ASR响应总耗时：11475
2018-12-01 16:03:36.126  INFO 11528 --- [t.baidu.com/...] com.asrapi.service.HTTPService     : http://audiotest.baidu.com/open_asr_test/up?id=76cfe0da-6f09-43ef-91a4-53c395387aa4, resp_code:200
2018-12-01 16:03:36.126  INFO 11528 --- [t.baidu.com/...] com.asrapi.service.HTTPService     : http://audiotest.baidu.com/open_asr_test/up?id=76cfe0da-6f09-43ef-91a4-53c395387aa4, resp_message:OK
2018-12-01 16:03:36.126  INFO 11528 --- [t.baidu.com/...] com.asrapi.service.HTTPService     : http://audiotest.baidu.com/open_asr_test/up?id=76cfe0da-6f09-43ef-91a4-53c395387aa4, resp_encoding:null
2018-12-01 16:03:36.126  INFO 11528 --- [t.baidu.com/...] com.asrapi.service.HTTPService     : http://audiotest.baidu.com/open_asr_test/up?id=76cfe0da-6f09-43ef-91a4-53c395387aa4, resp_protocol:http/1.1
2018-12-01 16:03:36.126  INFO 11528 --- [t.baidu.com/...] com.asrapi.service.HTTPService     : http://audiotest.baidu.com/open_asr_test/up?id=76cfe0da-6f09-43ef-91a4-53c395387aa4, response text:
```

**From the logs as above, we can see "Down" request hang up "Up" request, and "Up" request continue when "Dwon" request finish.**

**Question 1**: I wnana know why up request was hang up.

**Question 2**: I wanna know why undertow hanlde two requests with the same one NIO thread.

**Question 3**: I wanna know why Undertow do **NOT** block "dwon" request outside if Undertow just have one single NIO thread left, or why Udertow do **NOT** use two NIO threads to hanlde "up" and "down" requests if Undertow still have more NIO threads.

As I know, Undertow NIO-thread = CPU Core, so there should be at least 4 NIO-thread in my spring-webflux project.

Comment: Please, describe your problem IN your post. It will better convince those who can help you to invest time in it and it will help users of our knowledge base to find this question and it's answers in the future.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I have post a snapshot of my webflux project log, and my questions.